# mediaItems.search_next() returns 400

Tags: python, google-api-python-client, google-photos, google-photos-api

Unable to get all results of mediaItems.search:

```py
photos = google.get_service(credentials, 'photoslibrary', 'v1')
request = photos.albums().list(pageSize=50)
while request is not None:
    result = request.execute()
    for album in result['albums']:
        request2 = photos.mediaItems().search(body={'albumId': album['id']})
        while request2 is not None:
            result2 = request2.execute()
            request2 = photos.mediaItems().search_next(request2, result2)
            print('nextpageToken' in result2, request2)
    request = photos.albums().list_next(request, result)
```

Running this fails on the first search_next() call with

```
[...]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 851, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected end of string. Expected an object key or }.
```

That [library isn't really supported](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/651#issuecomment-488327682) it seems, so that might be the problem, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The google-api-python-client is generic client for all the [Google's discovery based APIs](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) and as such it supports all the API based on this protocol including the Photos one.

The correct way to use the services is to invoke the [build method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) and after that use the available methods of the services.

Beside this you always want to use `list_next` as `search_next` does not exists.

Here is an example of the photos API working on my laptop (python 3.6)

```py
import os
import pickle

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly', ]


# we check if we save the credentials in the past and we reuse them
if not os.path.exists('credentials.dat'):

    # no credentials found, we run the standard auth flow
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_local_server()

    with open('credentials.dat', 'wb') as credentials_dat:
        pickle.dump(credentials, credentials_dat)
else:
    with open('credentials.dat', 'rb') as credentials_dat:
        credentials = pickle.load(credentials_dat)

if credentials.expired:
    credentials.refresh(Request())

photos_sdk = build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# photos API
photos_albums_api = photos_sdk.albums()
photos_mediaitems_api = photos_sdk.mediaItems()

albums_list_params = {
    'pageSize': 50,
}

# first request
albums_list_req = photos_albums_api.list(**albums_list_params)

while albums_list_req is not None:
    photos_albums_list = albums_list_req.execute()

    # print(photos_albums_list)

    for album in photos_albums_list['albums']:
        print(album['title'])

        mediaitems_search_req = photos_mediaitems_api.search(body={'albumId': album['id']})

        while mediaitems_search_req is not None:
            mediaitems_search = mediaitems_search_req.execute()

            print(mediaitems_search)

            # mediaItems pagination management
            mediaitems_search_req = photos_mediaitems_api.list_next(mediaitems_search_req, mediaitems_search)

    # albums pagination handling
    albums_list_req = photos_albums_api.list_next(albums_list_req, photos_albums_list)
```

Comment: This is correct. Even though the python API shows the `search_next()` method to me, it's apparently a false positive, and you should (after calling e.g. `search()` once), follow up by running `list_next()` on the request and response returned by the first `search()` (or consecutive `list_next()`s.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more results than the specified `pageSize`, the API returns a `pageToken`, you should use to request the next part. See the example here [Access Google Photo API with Python using google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56611943/8641798)