# Google Photos API: UnknownApiNameOrVersion when using googleapiclient.discovery.build

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the Google Photos API with the Python client library googleapiclient.discovery.build method. However, I'm encountering an "UnknownApiNameOrVersion" error when attempting to create the client.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/path/to/service-account-file.json')
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary']
credentials = credentials.with_scopes(scopes)

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('photoslibrary', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: photoslibrary  version: v1
```

I've checked the documentation and examples, but I can't find a clear solution to this issue. Am I missing something in my code? Is there an alternative way to create the Google Photos API client?

I would appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this error and successfully create the Google Photos API client using the Python client library.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67094010/25991) from a very similar question.